# Delete layer created during Buffer_analysis

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am trying to figure out how to delete the layer that is created during the Buffer_analysis line.  I have searched all over the internet and have honestly tried about 100 different methods and cannot seem to find one that works.  If I was to type a layer "name" I can delete the layer, but in this case the layer name will be dependent upon the user input at `"outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)"`

This is only my second script so this is kicking my butt, I have been googling the heck out of this just to get this far, we have had zero teaching in our online class (just told to read a chapter and write a code).

**UPDATE:**
Here is my full script.

```py
# William Herzig
# Week 6 tool creation
# 6 Aug 2019

import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "\\\\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\\userprofiles$\\william.herzig\\Documents\\programming\\module_5_data\\week_5.gdb"           

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# List of all variables for the script
# User input variables (parameters)
# Input parameters for buffer tool
inPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
bufferDistance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

inPath1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
outPath1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
bufferDistance1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

inPath2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
outPath2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
bufferDistance2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)

# Input parameter Master Shape, used for clip tool, erase tool and Master Shape layer
natPark = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)

# Input variable for the final output feature class
finalOutput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)

# Pre-defined variables
buffered_area = "buffered_area"
clip = "clip"
clip1 = "clip1"
clip2 = "clip2"
layer_name = finalOutput
layer_name1 = "Master Shape"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)

# Clip tool, clipping the 3 input feature classes to the Master Shape.  This will reduce clutter and time due to less features for the buffer tool
arcpy.Clip_analysis(inPath, natPark, clip, "")
arcpy.Clip_analysis(inPath1, natPark, clip1, "")
arcpy.Clip_analysis(inPath2, natPark, clip2, "")


# Buffer tool, places a user defined buffer around each of the 3 input feature classes and exports to the user defined feature classes, also adds as a layer to the map
buffer1 = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(clip, outPath, bufferDistance)
buffer2 = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(clip1, outPath1, bufferDistance1)
buffer3 = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(clip2, outPath2, bufferDistance2)

# Union tool makes a single feature class by combining the 3 buffer outputs into one
arcpy.Union_analysis([buffer1, buffer2, buffer3], buffered_area, "ALL", "", "GAPS")

# Erase tool erases the Union features from the Master Shape (natPark parameter) and saves as the finalOutput parameter feature class
arcpy.Erase_analysis(natPark, buffered_area, finalOutput, "")

# Adds a layer for the Master Shape (natPark parameter)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(natPark, layer_name1)
add_layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_name1)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer1)

# Adds a layer for the finalOutput parameter (the result of the erase tool)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(finalOutput, layer_name)
add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_name)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
```

Comment: If you dont use the layer set `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap=False` prior to buffer

Comment: this does not work

Comment: Try using a refresh active view or arcpy.RefreshTOC().

Comment: Please provide an example of what `outPath` would contain.

Comment: The user will just select (or create) a feature class in the geodatabase.  So, for example the user will select "campsite_buffer" and the path would be C:\documents\python\week_6.gdb  I can add the full script if that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of name, go with the layer's `catalogPath` property. This will return the full path of the layer's feature class.

If `outPath` is the full path of the buffer output:

```
for layer in layerList:
    if arcpy.Describe (layer).catalogPath.lower () == outPath.lower ():
         arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, layer)
```

If `outPath` is the feature class name that gets saved in the workspace:

```
import os
for layer in layerList:
    if arcpy.Describe (layer).catalogPath.lower () == os.path.join (arcpy.env.workspace, clip).lower ():
         arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, layer)
```

Comment: these did not work either

Comment: I added standardizing paths with `.lower ()`. That might work. You might also have issues comparing paths if you use forward slashes in `outPath`.

Comment: Emil, I appreciate the help but none of these methods seem to work